# I need a regex result that does not include the substring at the beginning and end of the matched pattern

Tags: regex

I have a pattern I need to match that's always a date "_YYYYMMDD.". However, I don't want to include the "_" and the "." in the result. I have a regex pattern that successfully match above. Its too complicated to include here because I would have to write by hand and would mess it up.

Suffice it to say I have a pattern:

```
[_](lots of stuff in the middle)[.]
```

It works fine but I don't want to include the "_" and "."

Any answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the full regex, it's difficult to answer. But if your matched pattern is a string and it DOES contain `_` at the beginning and `.` at the end, I guess you can just do: `patternString = patternString.substring(1 , patternString.length-2);` to exclude the first and last indices out of that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching underscore and dot with the pattern and not including it in the full matching text, you will need to use lookarounds in the regex pattern. Following regex will match date preceded by `_` and followed by `.`

```
(?<=_)\d{8}(?=\.)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D5ehGj/1)**

Additionally, if you want to capture the year, month and date part into their own capture groups, you can use this regex and capture year part from group1, month from group2 and date from group3,

```
(?<=_)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(?=\.)
```

**[Demo with different parts of date into their own groups](https://regex101.com/r/D5ehGj/2)**

Comment: The above solution worked for me (except you don't escape the "."). Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy: Glad to help and you're welcome. And I did escape the dot as `\.` Two ways to escape, either put it in `[.]` or put a backslash before the dot `\.` Also please consider upvoting if my answer helped you.

Comment: I will totally upvote your answer (it solved my problem!). By the way, I think I was unclear. Your solution worked for only if I did NOT escape the ".". But thats a small detail. Thanks so much. You solved and helped me learn.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to slice the first and last characters off the result. You can do it either by string length:

```
result="${result:1:${#result}-2}"
```

(or `result="${result:1:8}"` since the length will be constant)

Or by specific character:

```
result="${result#_}"
result="${result%.}"
```